# Node js merge values basic implemenation

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to do something like the below but merge function has a problem with the line

`content = content.replace( content, "Hi" + values.first_name + "! Thanks for completing this code challenge :)" );`

**Filename : *app.js***

```
var utilities = require("./utilities");

var mailValues = {};

mailValues.first_name = "Janet";

var emailTemplate = "Hi %first_name%! Thanks for completing this code challenge :)";

var mergedContent = utilities.merge(emailTemplate, mailValues);

//mergedContent === "Hi Janet! Thanks for completing this code challenge :)";
```

**Filename : *utilities.js***

```
  function merge(content, values) {

  content = content.replace( content, "Hi" + values.first_name + "! Thanks for completing this code challenge :)" );
  return content;
}


module.exports.merge = merge;
```

Comment: I think there's a typo in your `merge() function`. It probably, should've been `content = content.replace("%first_name%", "Hi " + values.first_name + "! Thanks for completing this code challenge :)" );`

Comment: I had tried this. But this isn't correct too.

Comment: This works for me: `content.replace("%first_name%", values.first_name);`

Comment: is there a reason why you replace the entire content instead of doing something like this http://jsbin.com/domilejeqi/1/edit?js,output ?

Comment: hmm... not sure what's wrong in your code, OP... but it's a simple string replace. Oh and @Ziki comments are more correct than mine.

Comment: @Ziki @Marius @IronGeek I tried this but simply can't get it through some code engine.Okay here are the question instructions that might help .
`Complete the implementation of the merge method in utilities.js file. You should be able to pass in a string with placeholders with percent signs (%) surrounding them. The second parameter should be an object with values to be inserted in to the placeholders. Look at index.js to see how it should work`

Comment: @MegaRacer so you should use regex. you need to write function that can handle any replace, and get all the placeholders, and then replace them with the ref in the object.

Comment: Hmm But these templates are given already. 
The only thing which needs to be added is the line of content on utilities which I have tried to do by all ways mentioned.

Comment: The line `content = content.replace( content, "Hi" + values.first_name + "! Thanks for completing this code challenge :)" )` is not given. Rest everything is given as such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your merge function is not good, it does a weird thing and will surely returns a weird string if you pass another template. You're replacing the entire input string by the "Hi...." string but with first_name inserted so in the end, your function is too specific and can't handle extra parameters or another template/string.

```js
function merge(content, values) {
  // loop over all the keys in the values object
  Object.keys(values).forEach(function(key) {
    // look for the key surrounded by % in the string
    // and replace it by the value from values
    content = content.replace('%' + key + '%', values[key]);
  });
  return content;
}

var mailValues = {};
mailValues.first_name = "Janet";
mailValues.last_name = "Doe";
var emailTemplate = "Hi %first_name% %last_name%! Thanks for completing this code challenge :)";
var mergedContent = merge(emailTemplate, mailValues);

document.write(mergedContent);
```

Try the "run code snippet" button.

`for ... in` version, for information, better to use the previous version.

```js
function merge(content, values) {
  // loop over all the keys in the values object
  for (var key in values) {
    // look for the key surrounded by % in the string
    // and replace it by the value from values
    content = content.replace('%' + key + '%', values[key]);
  }
  return content;
}

var mailValues = {};
mailValues.first_name = "Janet";
mailValues.last_name = "Doe";
var emailTemplate = "Hi %first_name% %last_name%! Thanks for completing this code challenge :)";
var mergedContent = merge(emailTemplate, mailValues);

document.write(mergedContent);
```

Comment: It works. But can you also do it with "for in " loop. Please don't edit this one. Atleast I will learn both methods.

Comment: This works too for me.

` for (var key in values) {
    content = content.replace("%" + key + "%", values[key]);
}
`

Comment: I got your solution as well. Thanks !

Comment: Well, `for ... in` makes me uncomfortable but I added it. It's quite random and can returns inherited properties, `Object.keys()` returns only the object's own properties.

Comment: Ok got it. You are just missing var keyword before key in the loop declaration.

Comment: Ah yes, `for ... in` bothers me so much I forgot it.